# Align SweetAlert2 Content To Top of Popup

Tags: css, sweetalert2

I'm using a typeahead Vue component inside of a Swal2 popup, I've adjusted the height using a custom class so I can get all of the typeahead dropdown data inside (or what would appear inside) the popup.

But I can't seem to get the content to align to the top.

I'm sure it's just a flex box setting but I can't figure out what to add to my custom class the get this aligned top.

```
.lookup-custom-height {
    height: 400px;
}
```

> CODE REQUESTED:

```
lookup() {
    swal({
        title: 'Substance Lookup',
        html: '<sub-typeahead placeholder="Search for Substances ..." item="material" display="name"></sub-typeahead>',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        customClass: 'lookup-custom-height',
    })

    return new Vue({
        el: swal.getContent(),
        components: {
            SubTypeahead
        }
    })
},
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add your current code?

Comment: I don't see why that would matter. It's a sweetalert issue not an issue with the code, but I suppose I can add it.